# Pagination using Zend Db Sql

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, zend-framework2

I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/in-depth-guide/zend-db-sql-zend-hydrator/) on zend documentation to create the blog module from the beginning, finished and everything is working properly.
On the previous tutorial that was to create an album module they used `TableGateway` and also showed how to create the pagination with it, but in this blog module they didn't and they are using `Zend\Db\Sql`.

I tried to find something on the internet about that and nothing...

```
public function findAllPosts()
{
    $sql       = new Sql($this->db);
    $select    = $sql->select('posts');
    $statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $result    = $statement->execute();

    if (! $result instanceof ResultInterface || ! $result->isQueryResult()) {
        return [];
    }

    $resultSet = new HydratingResultSet($this->hydrator, $this->postPrototype);
    $resultSet->initialize($result);
    return $resultSet;
}
```

On the previous tutorial we created two methods, one called `fetchAll($paginated = false)` and another one called `fetchPaginatedResults`, if `$paginated` was true it called the method `fetchPaginatedResults`, for example:

```
public function fetchAll($paginated = false)
{
    if ($paginated) {
        return $this->fetchPaginatedResults();
    }

    return $this->tableGateway->select();
}

private function fetchPaginatedResults()
{
    // Create a new Select object for the table:
    $select = new Select($this->tableGateway->getTable());

    // Create a new result set based on the Album entity:
    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());

    // Create a new pagination adapter object:
    $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect(
        // our configured select object:
        $select,
        // the adapter to run it against:
        $this->tableGateway->getAdapter(),
        // the result set to hydrate:
        $resultSetPrototype
    );

    $paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
    return $paginator;
}
```

I was wondering, how to do the same using `Zend\Db\Sql` and `HydratingResultSet`?

Answer (score 0):

You must pick `$db_adapter` and you will get the paginator by :

```
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect;

$sql = new Sql($this->db);
$select = $sql->select('posts');
new Paginator(new DbSelect($select, $db_adpter));
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how would I pick the `$db_adapter` inside a method?

Comment: In a `TableGateway`, method `getAdapter()`, quite simply.

Answer (score 0):

you can set HydratingResultSet in Paginator.

Example:

```
    $sql = new Sql ( $this->db );
    $select = $sql->select ( $this->table );

    //$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject ( $select );
    //$result = $statement->execute ();     
    //if (! $result instanceof ResultInterface || ! $result->isQueryResult ()) {return [ ];}

    $resultSet = new HydratingResultSet ( $this->hydrator, $this->Prototype );
    //$resultSet->initialize ( $result );
    // return $resultSet;

    // Executando
    $adapter = new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect ( $select, $this->db, $resultSet );
    $paginator = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator ( $adapter );
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage ( $count );
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber ( $offset );

    return $paginator;
```

but if you will use Paginator, I'm not sure if the Hydrator is the best option.

*Remember*, you need to install the package (if it is zf3)

```
$ composer require zendframework/zend-paginator
Using version ^2.7 for zendframework/zend-paginator
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing zendframework/zend-paginator (2.7.0)
    Loading from cache


  Please select which config file you wish to inject 'Zend\Paginator' into:
  [0] Do not inject
  [1] config/modules.config.php
  [2] config/development.config.php.dist
  Make your selection (default is 0):1

  Remember this option for other packages of the same type? (y/N)
Installing Zend\Paginator from package zendframework/zend-paginator
zendframework/zend-paginator suggests installing zendframework/zend-cache (Zend\Cache component to support cache features)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```